# How do I contact the UFW developers to make a feature request?

Tags: firewall, ufw

I have some ideas for improving the package, but have been unable to locate any valid contact information.  The content information I did find bounced.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/ufw is a start, you'll find a bug reports link (where you're wishing to make a feature request).   Please ensure the feature doesn't already exist (esp. if you're using an older release; ie. check in the *development* release first).  You'll note the suggestion to *ask a question via Launchpad before contacting the maintainer directly*, so I'd suggest doing so (a launchpad question can be converted into bug report/feature-request and will likely carry more weight.  ie. https://answers.launchpad.net/

Comment: Many open source developers prefer "feature requests" to be accompanied by some kind of contribution to their project. Not money, but effort: Help with packaging, documentation, bug triage, graphic design, code, etc. Many projects have far more feature requests than developer time (or interest) to implemeting somebody else's idea for free. The contribution shows that you are serious about the idea and the future of that software, not another drive-by.

Answer (score 1):

The link https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/ufw contains package information and a load of other details, and is a start.

You'll find a bug reports link (*where you're wishing to make a feature request*).

Please ensure the feature doesn't already exist (esp. if you're using an older release; ie. check in the *development* release first).

You'll also note the suggestion to

> *ask a question via Launchpad before contacting the maintainer directly*

so I'd suggest doing so (*a launchpad question can be converted into bug report/feature-request and will likely carry more weight*) ie.  https://answers.launchpad.net/

Comment: Also, you might want to differentiate between a feature request _for the package_ and a feature request _for the software_ that the package maintainer build the package from. If it's about the package, you can reach out to the package maintainer (through a ticket on Launchpad, as guiverc mentioned). If it's about the software itself, you often find a link to the software's homepage. There you might find the necessary contact information. In the case of ufw, the project's homepage is the Launchpad page used for the package, so the two are the same, but that's more of an exception than the rule.

Comment: Good point... if it wasn't another package (which has an *upstream* I would have... Most packages I deal for sure do have, which means I create launchpad ticket, (usually verify the issue exists in another non-Ubuntu system, then go upstream create github/gitlab/.. or other ticket & link the two on launchpad etc.. but doesn't apply to this question).